# Non-deterministic finite state automoton

Tags: finite-automata, nondeterminism

I am taking a course in the theory of computation and am trying to understand how to correctly design NFA's so that I can transform them into regex. I was wondering if I have Sigma={a,b} and need to design a NFA over Sigma Star that has at least one of its last 2 characters to be an 'a'; Can I simply start 2 threads, one that will accept 'a' as the last character and the other will accept 'a' or 'b' in the second to last position and 'a' as the last symbol? Also, the fact that this will be over Sigma Star, would that also mean that I have to have epsilon transitions included in this design?[image: L(A)={w: at least one the last 2 characters of w is an 'a'}]

Comment: Previous question is "on hold" by Raphael and I can no longer edit or comment it, this is why I decided to resubmit with more details in terms of my question.

Comment: The same problems apply here as on your first attempt: (1) Your FA accepts the string $\mathtt{a}$ for which "last two characters" doesn't seem to apply. (2) The FA doesn't accept $\mathtt{ab}$, though it should. It shouldn't be too hard to redesign your attempt to address these two points.

Comment: The start state accepts any string of the form (aUb)* and as such shouldn't "ab" also be accepted?

Comment: @user116317 The start state isn't accepting.

Comment: Why can't you edit the first post? It's created by the same user, so editing should be possible. (Please look for the link beneath the post; it is not there, please visit us in [chat]).

Comment: @Raphael Whenever I try to edit the original question, I get:  This post is locked and cannot be edited.

Comment: @DavidRicherby  What I meant by accepting was that: since the start state takes all strings over the sigma*, and in order to go to the accepting state, has to be concatenated with be; wouldn't then accept ab?

Comment: @user116317: I can edit your old post just fine (but then, some restrictions don't apply to mods). Please try creating a proper account if you did not already to that.

Comment: I think I found the correct answer to this question and changed the initial image.  Thank you to everyone who helped me solve this.